# Copying text into clipboard on asp.net button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can any one please help me how to copy text into clipboard on asp.net button click.on button click text has copied into clients clipboard.

Thanks 
AnkiReddy

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works with IE.

```
<textarea id='txtCopyToClipboard' rows="3">This text will copy to your clipboard</textarea>
<br />    
<input type="button" id='btnCopy' text="ClickHereToCopy"
onclick="clipboardData.setData('Text',document.getElementById('txtCopyToClipboard').value);"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Syed Ali Taqi i need solution for other browsers too.